# "Can't replace template post_upvote because it hasn't been defined yet." error

Tags: telescope

Since the update to the i18n branch from the master branch, I've the follow error :

`Can't replace template post_upvote because it hasn't been defined yet.`

I'm using the Newton theme.
Do you know where this come from?

Answer (score 1):

The `post-upvote` template has been renamed `post-upvote` to manage the downvote option now
Here is the commit:
https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/blob/05f656a407a64a56654f026e3d0ee5cdf7062b38/packages/telescope-posts/lib/client/templates/modules/post_vote.html

Answer (score 0):

The Scopemount themes will be updated when the new Telescope release comes out. If I were to update earlier then new installs would break.